# Sending and Receiving Data Failed with Swift Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am building an iOS app for a card game played by 4 people. I plan to use Multipeer Connectivity framework. So I started by learning from a chat app and modified it into a group chat app. (I copied some code from [Building a Chat App in Swift Using Multipeer Connectivity Framework](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/) )

When only 2 or 3 devices are connected, everything works well, but when I tried 4 devices, I encountered this problem: 
The message delivering between some devices could fail sometimes. For example, in one test, D can not send message to C, while A, B and C can send message to all the others.

I doubted it's the connection problem. So I printed out `session.connectedPeers.count` to check if all the devices have 3 connected peers. And they did. I also listed all of them as a proof.

I searched some related questions online and there are answers saying advertising and browsing at the same time can cause connection problem. So I avoided doing this. I've tried making one device advertising and the other three browsing, and also tried making three devices browsing and one advertising. In addition, I turned off advertising and browsing (after connection) when the group chat starts. But none of them solved my problem.

Now I guess it has something to do with sending data, I don't get an error though. I wonder is it guaranteed that all the peers in `session.connectedPeers` could receive the data? Or how should handle the sending and receiving process for a group chat?

Here is my code to send data: (When message is entered, it is sent to other devices in the chat group)

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()     
    let text = textField.text as String!
    let messageDictionary: [String: String] = ["message": text]   
    let messageData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(messageDictionary)

    do {
        try appDelegate.mpcManager.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcManager.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }

    let dictionary: [String: String] = ["sender": "self", "message": text]
    messagesArray.append(dictionary)
    self.updateTableview()
    textField.text = ""       
    return true
}
```

Here is how data is received:

```
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["data": data, "fromPeer": peerID]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receivedMPCDataNotification", object: dictionary)
}


func handleMPCReceivedDataWithNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Get the dictionary containing the data and the source peer from the notification.
    let receivedDataDictionary = notification.object as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    // "Extract" the data and the source peer from the received dictionary.
    let data = receivedDataDictionary["data"] as? NSData
    let fromPeer = receivedDataDictionary["fromPeer"] as! MCPeerID

    // Convert the data (NSData) into a Dictionary object.
    let dataDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data!) as! Dictionary<String, String>

    // Check if there's an entry with the "message" key.
    if let message = dataDictionary["message"] {

        // Create a new dictionary and set the sender and the received message to it.
        let messageDictionary: [String: String] = ["sender": fromPeer.displayName, "message": message]

        // Add this dictionary to the messagesArray array.
        messagesArray.append(messageDictionary)

        // Reload the tableview data and scroll to the bottom using the main thread.
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.updateTableview()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code in your question. in order to troubleshoot your code/ design look at the source code of an example app provided by apple.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Listings/AdhocGroupChat_SessionContainer_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013691-AdhocGroupChat_SessionContainer_m-DontLinkElementID_16 
you should be able to understand the syntax even though it's written in objective c 
Also here is also a good tutorial in swift + Source code
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/